# How to recover a crashed EventMachine loop

Tags: ruby, heroku, unicorn, eventmachine

I'm using Unicorn on Heroku and I created an EventMachine loop:
(from https://gist.github.com/jonkgrimes/5103321)

```
after_fork do |server,worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  if defined?(EventMachine)
    unless EventMachine.reactor_running? && EventMachine.reactor_thread.alive?
      if EventMachine.reactor_running?
        EventMachine.stop_event_loop
        EventMachine.release_machine
        EventMachine.instance_variable_set("@reactor_running",false)
      end
      Thread.new { EventMachine.run }
    end
  end

  Signal.trap("INT") { EventMachine.stop }
  Signal.trap("TERM") { EventMachine.stop }
end
```

The EventMachine works great, but at some point my events start failing because "no eventmachine loop is running." I imagine two possible problems:

- the loop is still running but somehow my unicorn forks are no longer bound properly (seems unlikely)
- the loop crashed (seems likely)

How can I detect and restart a crashed eventmachine? And/or how should I go about debugging this problem?

Comment: I do not understand why they run EM on a separate thread. Do you know why?

Comment: otherwise it would block the server from responding to HTTP requests

Comment: as you might have guessed from my previous comment I have never worked with Unicorn. But, first, I would set up a global error handler: http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#error_handler-class_method Although I doubt that it will tell you anything.

Comment: Seems to be working. I'm not getting the "no loop" errors anymore. I'll need to dig some more to figure out why it was crashing in the first place, but this is definitely a step in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: strange, the presence of a global event handler should not affect whether it works or not...

Comment: no? I think before, when I didn't have a handler, errors would just bubble all the way up and ultimately stop the loop. Now that I'm catching and handling them, they never make it high enough up the chain to stop the loop. But that's just an educated guess, idk if that's actually how it works.